# Cucumber with Ruby: Can it be used from a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I'd like to develop some reusable step definitions and scenario outlines for Cucumber in Ruby.

I've scoured the [Cucumber wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/_pages) but there seems to be no info on use of Cucumber with Ruby gems.

Is there support for execution of a feature from an installed Gem?

Or would a user have to manually change to the gem installation directory and explicitly referenced the feature(s) to run from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, all you need is to create some lib for reusable definitions and steps, and then require this lib(or gem) in `features/support/env.rb`

Here is a gem does exactly the same as you need, you can use it as a reference: https://github.com/jayzes/cucumber-api-steps

Look at the features this gem provide: https://github.com/jayzes/cucumber-api-steps/blob/master/features/request.feature The gem created some reusable parts.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Billy. I can't find rigorous documentation for `env.rb` anywhere on the Cucumber wiki, is this a Cucumber-specific file or something else..?

Comment: @KomodoDave, I'm happy my answer helps. For `env.rb`, yes it is a Cucumber native feature. I read it from "The Cucumber Book", and there is some introduction in Wiki, though not obvious https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks -- See the Global Hook part

Comment: this is where I had seen reference to the file. Thank you for providing the link. It's understandable the authors want you to buy the book so they reap some reward for their library I suppose :)

Comment: `env.rb` is not a must, any file name will do as long as it is in `features/support` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `cucumber --help` shows the way:

```
cucumber -r gem-name feature-name.feature
```

UPDATE: This doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [cucumber gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/cucumber) which installs the binary `cucumber`.

Running this command, will assume default settings. This means it will look under `./features` relative to the current path for files with the `.feature` extension. It will expect `./features/step_definitions` to hold files with `*_step.rb`, where it will search for steps.

Edit: never mind, I misread your question and thought you wanted to know about the cucumber gem and its default paths.